# Run another python file that shows camera preview using Tkinter window

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I want run python file which opens camera preview by Tkinter button that placed on the main window.But it runs automatically camera window without opening the main window when executing the code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os


window = tk.Tk()


window.title("Camera")
window.geometry("640x480")

lbl=Label(window,text="Start", font=("Arial Bold",10))
lbl.grid(column=0,row=0)
btn = Button(window, text="Start",command=os.system('capture.py'))
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `command=lambda: os.system('capture.py')`:

```
btn = Button(window, text="Start",command=lambda: os.system('capture.py'))
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

If you use `()` near a function name, it will call the function immediately. Which is not what you want, you want it to be called upon press, so just pass the function name(with `lambda` if it has arguments) and `tkinter` will handle the rest.